# EmguCV C# Contour detection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I need help in this part of code. I need to make my contours visible on black Background when Check Box is checked. But, when I set a tick in Check Box, my contours are disappear. Code and Screen shot below.  [That's my screenshot][1]

```
private Image<Bgr, byte> Find(Image<Bgr, byte> image)
    {
      Image<Gray, byte> outputImage = image.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(255)); //перевод изображения в серый цвет и уменьшение шума

      VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

      Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

      CvInvoke.FindContours(outputImage, contours, hierarchy, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.Tree, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

      if (checkBox1.Checked)
      {
        Image<Gray, byte> blackBackground = new Image<Gray, byte>(outputImage.Width, outputImage.Height, new Gray(0));

        CvInvoke.DrawContours(blackBackground, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));

        pictureBox2.Image = blackBackground.Bitmap;
      }
      else
      {
        CvInvoke.DrawContours(image, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));

        pictureBox2.Image = image.Bitmap;
      }

      return image;
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdtUb.png
```

Comment: I think MvcScalar has a constructor with 1 parameter, maybe using it will fix the problem because you are actually drawing on the single-channel image if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always render your screenshots in the post. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) and [edit] your post.

Comment: @GiorgiChkhikvadze I change the MCvScalar to 1 parameter (255). Nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a copy of the bitmap and assign to the picturebox like this?

```
pictureBox2.Image = blackBackground.ToBitmap();
```

or

```
pictureBox2.Image = image.ToBitmap();
```